# SSL Port Check on Mac

Tags: ssl

I have a MacBook Pro, and I want to see if a particular port, 8181, is indeed open and running SSL, as I have set in my GlassFish server.

Is there a command I can issue to see what is serving on which ports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Terminal:

$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:8181

This will connect to the localhost port 8181 using SSL.

Answer (score 1):

`netstat -ltnp`

Answer (score 1):

If it is publicly accessible, you can try online at http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Just specify the port after the colon (126.128.791.151:8081)

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -tulpn
```

But I have no experience with it, just guessed.